# How to show video clip in a list with Ruby on Rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have uploaded videos but when I see them in list, I would like to see a snapshot or clip of the video. Is there a way to display a list videos like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to generate images from a video.

You'll find [here](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/2/22/video-thumbnails-with-ffmpeg-and-paperclip) a tutorial allowing you to use [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to upload a video and FFMpeg to make a thumbnail out of it.

In that tutorial, what's interesting for making the thumbnail is the `make` method.
Which generates a ffmpeg command and executes it.

You'll find informations about that command alone [here](http://stream0.org/2008/02/howto-extract-images-from-a-vi.html).

Comment: Just a quick word of warning about using FFMPEG, from my understanding, although its free software its licensed under the LGPL or GPL which means you have to open source your code.

Comment: Correct me if wrong: It is not the case. If the *code* of FFMPEG is used to create some other software, then it will have to be GPLed. I am using RoR to develop an application. RoR is MIT that does not mean I will have to open source the code of my application.

Comment: @Josh K, you can use the *result* of FFMPEG execution (the converted video) in your application without any restrictions.  It is explicitly stated so in GPL.  LGPL is even less restrictive than GPL.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload videos & images with Paperclip, it uses a [`processor`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor) to create different variations of the file

The processor depends on the type of file, and will typically be [imagemagick](http://imagemagick.org) if you're working with images, and [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) if you're working with video

The way this works is that Paperclip will handle the file upload, and then send to the various processor to change. That's how you can generate the thumbnails with imagemagick, or the video thumbnail with ffmpeg

---

**paperclip-ffmpeg**

FFMpeg will be the best way to create a video thumbnail, and you can actually put it to work by installing the [`paperclip-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg) gem

Here is some live code showing how this works (you basically just have to call the `:ffmpeg` processor:

```
 has_attached_file :attachment,
                styles:          lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}}},
                :processors => lambda { |a| a.is_video? ? [ :ffmpeg ] : [ :thumbnail ] }

    def is_video?
            attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(video)
    end

    def is_image?
            attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image)
    end
```

If you need some more help with this (obviously the question was a long time ago), please let me know!